# Adding paths using matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use a function defined in another folder but I can't figure out to add it to the path list, all commands that I try are just making the program not respond, here is the basic code;

```
clear all; % clear all variables from the workspace
video = mmread('Video1.mpeg'); % call the function mmread to load the video.
```

The mmread is another folder inside the directory, however no matter what I try I cannot get the program to add it to the path without crashing (not responding)

Comment: Have you tried `addpath`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
addpath('/your/path')
```

remember that your m-file and the function defined in it MUST have the same same.

```
% file mmread.m
function ... = mmread(...)
  ...
end
```